# How can I see where my object locate manually

Tags: ceph

Instead of performing a lookup in the metadata table for every client request, the
CRUSH algorithm enables the client to independently computes where data should
be written to or read from. By deriving this metadata dynamically, there is no need to
manage a centralized table. I know CRUSH use rjenkins HASH. but I want to do it 
manually to see where my data go and how CRUSH locate my replica manually. 
I want to learn more a bout how ceph works.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is the [CRUSH white paper](https://ceph.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/weil-crush-sc06.pdf) by Sage A. Weil, Scott A. Brandt, Ethan L. Miller and Carlos Maltzahn. Enjoy the read.

Update:

And of course there is the an [article about RADOS](https://ceph.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/weil-rados-pdsw07.pdf) the fundamental storage of Ceph. Same authors.